# OrientDB: How to check if query result isn't empty in server side function?

Tags: javascript, orientdb, orientdb3.0

OrientDB allows for creating server side functions by using "Functions Management" in OrientDB Studio.
I'm using demo database and trying to find out if id from parameter exist in database (easy case). My problem is how to check if query result is empty? Code and more details below.

I have easy function in JS:

```
var queryResult = db.query('select Name from Castles where Id=?',id);
if(queryResult == null){
    response.send(404,"Castle not found", "text/plain", "Error: Castle not found");
}else{
    return queryResult;
}
```

Image of my Function Management code:
[function body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCM7P.png)

When I run this function with parameter 1 (id=1) then I got execution result:

[
    {
        "Name": "Castel Sant’Angelo"
    }
]

BUT (and here is a problem) when I do the same with parameter id=1234 then I got:

[

]

In second case I should get response "Error: Castle not found".

I tried change second line of code as:

```
if(queryResult == undefined)
if(queryResult["Name"] == null)
if(queryResult.length == 0)
and so on...but the result is the same
```

I'm using:
Studio version : 3.0.24
OrientDB version : 3.0.24

I can't find in documentation how to check if query result isn't empty in OrientDB 3.0.X

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help you. It's the same logic but implemented in OrientDB-SQL:

```sql
    let $queryResult = select Name from Castles where Id = :id;
    if ($queryResult.size() = 0) {
        return "Error: Castle not found";
    }
    return $queryResult;
```

This should give you:

`select checkIfCastleExist(1)`: [ { "Name": "Castel Sant’Angelo" } ]

`select checkIfCastleExist(1234)`: [ { "value":"Error: Castle not found" } ]